# How to use CameraX with PreviewView?

Tags: java, camera, android-camera, android-camerax

I can't find out how to use camerax with previewview.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use `Camerax` with `PreviewView`, the code uses the latest versions of CameraX, meaning camera-camera2 version 1.1.0-beta01, and camera-view version 1.1.0-beta01.

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        previewView = view.findViewById(R.id.preview_view);
  

        setCameraProviderListener();

    }
```

```
private void setCameraProviderListener() {
        ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture =
                ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(requireContext());
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(() -> {

            try {
                ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                bindPreview(cameraProvider);
            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                // No errors need to be handled for this Future
                // This should never be reached
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(requireContext()));
    }
```

```
 private void bindPreview(ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
        
        imageAnalyser();
        imageCapture();

        CameraSelector cameraSelector =
                new CameraSelector.Builder().requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();


        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getSurfaceProvider());

        ViewPort viewPort = previewView.getViewPort();

        if (viewPort != null) {
            UseCaseGroup useCaseGroup = new UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                    .addUseCase(preview)
                    .addUseCase(imageAnalyzer)
                    .addUseCase(imageCapture)
                    .setViewPort(viewPort)
                    .build();

            cameraProvider.unbindAll();
            Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup);
            CameraControl cameraControl = camera.getCameraControl();
            cameraControl.setLinearZoom((float)0.3);
        }


    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
        android:id="@+id/preview_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/Yellow"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How to set TextureView instead of PreviewView, not able to set the Preview 
preview.setSurfaceProvider(textureView.getSurfaceProvider());
shows error in latest version 1.0.0-rc01

Comment: you must use previewView.getSurfaceProvider() instead of textureView.getSurfaceProvider() in the preview.setSurfaceProvider()

Comment: Thank you @MohamedBenRomdhane, your answer works like a charm, I just did an adjust on preview.setSurfaceProvider(), changing the getSurfaceProvider for previewView.createSurfaceProvider() on version 1.0.0-alpha14

Comment: @MohamedBenRomdhane it was the version that I was used when I started my project, now I have to upgrade that.

Comment: Soooo, where exactly do you put that piece of code? It's really not obvious for some people.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/display-a-camera-preview-with-previewview-86562433d86c) is an article that explains `PreviewView` and how to use it. It's valid up to version 1.0.0-alpha10 of camera-view, I'll try to keep it up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I had set `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` while debugging a *different* error, and had forgotten to remove it (or set it to `true`). I quickly noticed camera functionality had stopped working.

Make sure there is no `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your apps manifest. If there is, either remove it, or set it to `true`. If this is set to `false` it will affect the camera preview stream.

**TL;DR**

Remove any `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your manifest, or set it `true`.