# Cannot resolve method 'setPreferredImplementationMode' in 'PreviewView'

Tags: java, android, qr-code, android-camerax

I am a beginner in Andriod and have a problem now.

How to Create a QR Code Scanner with CameraX and ZXing is described in [here](https://learntodroid.com/how-to-create-a-qr-code-scanner-app-in-android/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60301296/how-to-use-camerax-with-previewview/68334058#68334058). I'm trying to make a sample project.

But I have an error in code

```
private PreviewView previewView;
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    previewView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_previewView);
...
}
...
private void bindCameraPreview(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {
    previewView.setPreferredImplementationMode(PreviewView.ImplementationMode.SURFACE_VIEW);
...
}
```

Error is "Cannot resolve method 'setPreferredImplementationMode' in 'PreviewView'". There is no 'SURFACE_VIEW' in 'PreviewView.ImplementationMode' too.

Please help me fix this problem.

Android Studio 4.1.2, a project for Android 9.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably due to the version of `androidx.camera:camera-view` that you're using.

`setPreferredImplementationMode` became available in version `1.0.0-alpha09`, and was later renamed to [`setImplementationMode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#setImplementationMode(androidx.camera.view.PreviewView.ImplementationMode)).

`PreviewView`'s implementation modes `TEXTURE_VIEW` and `SURFACE_VIEW` were renamed in version `1.0.0-alpha15` to [`COMPATIBLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode#COMPATIBLE) and [`PERFORMANCE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView.ImplementationMode#PERFORMANCE) respectively.

Comment: Thank you! What shell I do with next 'preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.crecreateSurfaceProvider());'? PreviewView.crecreateSurfaceProvider must be renamed too?

Comment: Yes, it was renamed to [`getSurfaceProvider()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getSurfaceProvider()).